# Getting an app version and what's new from google store

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play

My current code works perfectly fine to get current version from google store,
But is theres away to get both current version and whats new in the same response ?
I want to recommend the user an update if the application is updated on play store and the user still using an older version.
Here's my code below

```
public class AppVersion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final String packageName;
    private final Listener listener;

    public interface Listener {
        void result(String version);
    }

    AppVersion(String packageName, Listener listener) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getPlayStoreAppVersion(String.format("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s", packageName));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String version) {
        listener.result(version);
    }

    @Nullable
    private static String getPlayStoreAppVersion(String appUrlString) {
        String
                currentVersion_PatternSeq = "<div[^>]*?>Current\\sVersion</div><span[^>]*?>(.*?)><div[^>]*?>(.*?)><span[^>]*?>(.*?)</span>",
                appVersion_PatternSeq = "htlgb\">([^<]*)</s";
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(appUrlString).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                StringBuilder sourceCode = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) sourceCode.append(line);

                // Get the current version pattern sequence
                String versionString = getAppVersion(currentVersion_PatternSeq, sourceCode.toString());
                if (versionString == null) return null;

                // get version from "htlgb">X.X.X</span>
                return getAppVersion(appVersion_PatternSeq, versionString);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    private static String getAppVersion(String patternString, String input) {
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            if (pattern == null) return null;
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            if (matcher.find()) return matcher.group(1);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and to call the method i use

```
   new AppVersion(context.getPackageName(), version ->
                Log.d("app version test", String.format("App version: %s", version)
                )).execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is a bad design for your App. You should not rely on scraping to Play store to show a prompt to the user to upgrade. What if the Play Store decides to change design of their HTML? You could leave all your users in a buggy situation.

A much better solution would be to use something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). Have your app read the minimum allowed version code from this. Then it is completely controllable by you, and you don't even have to write a server - firebase does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get App version from BuildConfig Class:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString()
```

1 more thing i want to clear that **you cannot get the app version of published app on playstore.**.

You can put your version code on your backend server and then check this code with your current app version through api call.

i think this will help you.

Comment: Yes you can with the method i linked above and its working fine as i said, and than i compare it with BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE and if its > current installed version than i show him dialog to update, but my question is how to get update note same as the version